# How can I place zeroes to the left of a given number to a maximum of 6 digits including the given numbers

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have this method that receives an ID number and downloads an HTML website according to that ID.

Typically, an IMDB link is like this:

```
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0892791/
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1226229/
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0000429/
```

They all follow the 'tt' then 7 digits, with lack of digits turning into zeroes to fill out the left spaces.

How can I accomplish this using C#? I'm kind of stumped.

Here's my method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Find a movie page using its precise IMDB id.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">IMDB Movie ID</param>
/// <returns>Returns an HtmlDocument with the source code included.</returns>
public HtmlDocument ByID(string id)
{
    string url = String.Format("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt{0}/", id);            
    HtmlDocument page = downloader.Load(url);
    return page;
}
```

Thank you very much for your time, and if you are interested in helping out, you can check out the complete source code of TheFreeIMDB here:
http://thefreeimdb.codeplex.com/

Comment: Might should be aware of this: http://www.imdb.com/help/show_leaf?usedatasoftware, esp: "The data must be taken only from the plain text data made available from our FTP sites (see http://www.imdb.com/interfaces for more details and for links to our FTP servers). You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar online data gathering and extraction tools on our website."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `id` is a string in your sample, use `id.PadLeft(length, '0')`, where `length` is the total length you want (in this case: 7).

Comment: Worked exactly how I wanted it to. Thank you! Wait for time to pass and I'll accept the answer. It's 8 minutes until I can do that.